# Ios how to access google analytics reporting from ios

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an app that is using google analytics to track usage of the app and it works great using GANTracker api. I can see results and analysis when logging on the google analytics web site.

I nowneed to access to these stats with my apps to see what are the top topics or top subject users are interested in, so i would need to be able to do read and request to google analytics.
I've seen that there is a reporting api in java but i have not seen any ios calls or api to read stats from google analytics?

Has anyone done that and can share how you did it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's a post that can help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020290/get-data-from-google-analytics-using-the-core-reporting-api-skd-via-objective][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020290/get-data-from-google-analytics-using-the-core-reporting-api-skd-via-objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has made an Objective C library available which you can use to access JSON APIs, including the Analytics API. You can find the library at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/.